# Bootstrap add margin to element

Tags: css

```css
.row {background-color:lavender}

.col1{
 margin:3px;
 min-height:300px;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:silver;
}

.col2{
 margin:3px;
 min-height:300px;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#faebd7;
}

.col3{
 margin:3px;
 min-height:300px;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:skyblue;
}
```

I have a question.  When I put a heading in the center column Bootstrap seems to add margin (please see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8HiC.png)).  Is this the default behavior? I have included both the CSS and HTML.  If I add just text into
the content the margins do not move, so perhaps it's adding margin
to the Header element?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

  </head>
  <body>
    
 <div class="container">
 
   <div class="row">
   
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="col1">column 1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="col2"><h2> Column 2 <small> Secondary text </small> </h2></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="col3">column 3</div>
   </div>
     </div>
  
   </div>
    
 </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: show us your css also to see your problem

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ran this code, but my guess is the margin on the `h2` element.